# How to provide a sensitive data to nose

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, nose

I am using nose to test a Python class that requires a username and password. What is the best practice for providing that username and password pair to the test module? I'd like the testing process to be intuitive for another engineer to pick up, and I cannot store any sensitive information in cleartext. Any ideas?

Comment: The answer is -- it depends. Can you describe what your testing?

Comment: The class needs to be initialized with a username and password in order to access an API on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most common options is to provide data in env variables.

```
import os

password = os.environ['PASSWORD']
username = os.environ['USERNAME']
```

`$ USERNAME=user PASSWORD=qwerty nose`

Note: Environment variables can be read by root and process owner. Variables provided via command line appear in shell history with the command.

### Manual tests

- encourage (enforce) developers to obtain their own credentials,
- encrypt credentials; among others I would take a look at [git-secret](https://sobolevn.github.io/git-secret/). Tox could be used to automate this a bit.

### Automated tests

Most CI systems offer option (internally or via plugin) to store and pass credentials to test/build plans, mask them in logs. For example [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) has numerous plugins [Mask Password](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin), [Credentials Binding](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin). Atlassian's Bamboo by default masks all plan variables if name has `password` word. Personally, I found the most useful are Travis' [encrypted variables](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Encrypted-Variables), credentials are tied to repo/commit, not to plan.